# Firebase RemoteMessage has filled Bundle but getData() is empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My firbase RemoteMessage has a mBundle with 12 key value pairs, according to debugger, those field were filled [image].

But when I say: `remoteMessage.getData();` the resulting ArrayMap `Map<String, String>` has size 0 and thus no elements.

**How can I access the Map of remoteMessage?**

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: Nevermind, @sampo02 answer helped me

Answer (score 15):

I know this might be late but You can get the data from Notification Object in RemoteMessage

```
String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
```

hope this helps

Comment: remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(); throws a NullPointerException. The getNotification is null.

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered same problem.
And finally fixed this problem.
In my case, server side's sending FCM payload problem.
like this.

```
options = {
  priority: 'high',
  notification: {
    title: "title",
    body: "message",
    url: "some_url",
    image_url: "some_image_url"
  }
```

And I updated like following,

```
options = {
  priority: 'high',
  notification: {
    title: "title",
    body: "message",
  },
  data: {
    url: "some_url",
    image_url: "some_image_url"
  }
```

After that, I could get payload values by `remoteMessage.getData()`.

Comment: To same , not work for me ! because bundle not have in remoteMessage.getData() . Data.size == 0

Comment: I have implemented same code but still remoteMessage.getData().size() returns 0.

Comment: i believe 
if the app is not in foreground Android it needs special overriding sendNotification(), and we have to manually build notification to show as popup when the app is in foreground, in this case "RemoteMessage.getData.get("title") only works and as mentioned above the FCM payload should contain both objects - notification and data 

If the app is in background Android needs "RemoteMessage.getNotification()"

Comment: As stated by jalillrfan , the receiving of data differs based on app is in foreground or background .
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages

app message

Answer (score 3):

The debugger **initially** showed the `data` field as empty, but calling `getData()` returned the result, and the debugger then showed the correct map.